# extending rsyslog's default logging template

Tags: linux, rsyslog

Using centos 7, i would like to extend rsyslogs standard template.

I actually don't know if, the default template is hardcoded or explicitly  defined in a config-file or so?

Anyway, using the standard produces this:
`Sep 11 14:01:01 <hostname> root: Hello from /etc/cron.hourly/test_hourly`

I would like to extend it, so that it changes to this:
`Sep 11 14:01:01 <hostname> local1.notice root: Hello from /etc/cron.hourly/test_hourly`

In other words, I would like to include the text "local1.notice",
"local1.notice" is only an example, 
it is the result when I use `rsyslogs-predefined variables:
%syslogfacility-text%.%syslogseverity-text%`

I already tried to use a new template,
by including the following two lines in my /etc/rsyslig.conf

`$template sample_template,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogfacility-text%.%syslogseverity-text% %msg%\n"
local1.*     /var/log/local1.log;sample_template`

But this approach leads to lines like this:

```
Sep 11 10:01:01 <hostname> local1.notice Hello from /etc/cron.hourly/test_hourly
Sep 11 14:01:01 <hostname> local1.notice root: Hello from /etc/cron.hourly/test_hourly
```

As you can see, the `root:` - part is missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

answering my own question, the

```
%syslogtag%
```

entry was simply missing...

Changing the syntax also to the new template config-syntax,
here are the resulting lines from my /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
# old:
# Use default timestamp format
# $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
# new:
template (name="sample_template" type="string" string="%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogfacility-text%.%syslogseverity-text% %syslogtag% %msg%\n")
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate sample_template
```